# after insalling devstack http://server-ip:5000 not accessible

Tags: openstack, keystone

I followed https://www.theurbanpenguin.com/installing-devstack-on-ubuntu-16-04/ tutorial to install devstack(queens release) on my Ubuntu 16.04 server.

After the installation was done I ran the following commands

```
export OS_USERNAME=admin
export OS_TENANT_NAME=admin
export OS_PASSWORD=<password>
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://server-ip:5000/v2.0
openstack image create --public --disk-format qcow2 --container-format bare --file /home/cse3/ubuntu_images/ubuntu-14.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img ubuntu
```

But whenever I open http://server-ip:5000/v2.0 in my browser I am getting **unable to connect** error.
When I create an image from the command line I get the following message

`Failed to discover available identity versions when contacting http://server-ip:5000/v2.0. Attempting to parse version from URL.
Unable to establish connection to http://server-ip:5000/v2.0/tokens: HTTPConnectionPool(host='server-ip', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2.0/tokens (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f84ebecabd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))`

Can anyone suggest what steps need to be followed to remove this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing the Devstack, you should be able to view the OpenStack dashboard at `http://server-ip` if the `server-ip` is a public IP. The `AUTH_URL` is for you to authorize the API when you are using the SDK or the client library. And this is actually how the dashboard (Horizon) works with the Keystone identity service.

If the `server_ip` is not a public IP, you need to set up a proxy port in your server and your browser.

Comment: When I open `http://server-ip` in my browser I am able to view the OpenStack dashboard. I want to use `http://server-ip:5000/v2.0`  for creating a PoP for an OpenStack VIM instance in [OpenBaton](https://openbaton.github.io/documentation/pop-registration/)

Comment: Great, and as for creating a PoP, it is out of the scope for this question I believe. Would you mind asking another question about that?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the identity API changed from

`export OS_AUTH_URL=http://server-ip:5000/v2.0`

to

`export OS_AUTH_URL=http://server-ip/identity`

You can get more from the [OpenStack Doc](https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/rocky/install/keystone-openrc-ubuntu.html#creating-the-scripts)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21674528)

Comment: @IanLim it does answer the question. Also, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256360/6296561

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice this  before

Answer (score 0):

Check your httpd is running

systemctl status httpd

If it is exited or not started .

Enable the httpd

systemctk s

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?